# git merge не все сливает

Tags: git, git-merge

Сливаю текущую ветку с веткой Dev, сливаю такой командой

```
   git merge -X theirs Dev --squash
```

мне нужно что бы все что есть в Dev переписалось, как если бы я скопировал файлы с заменой. Однако после мержа делаю

```
git diff Dev
```

и есть отличия, вот откуда они там и как все же мне перенести все из ветки Dev поверх того что есть в текущей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас неверные ожидания. Флаг `-X theirs` в случае конфликтов берёт «их» версию.
Во всём остальном это обычный `git merge`.

Если вам нужно просто заменить всё в текущей ветке на `Dev`, то вам нужна команда
`git reset`. Возможно `git reset --merge Dev` или `git reset --hard Dev`.

**Осторожно!** Прежде чем играться с `git reset` убедитесь, что у вас всё закоммичено и сохранено и прочитайте документацию.